# c++ boost log stop: multi-thread on android

Tags: android, c++, multithreading, boost

I'm working on logs for a project which need the possibility to filter those logs (there is currently a tone of them, so much that a lambda person cannot track the flow of error and debug).

For this I tried using boost::log since it's rich in features and provided all I needed, however boost::log crash for a reason I don't understand.
The project is running under android, we use boost 1.57 and gcc 4.9.2.

We tried running the code on a linux machine and there is no problem.
Here is a small app in which the problem arise.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <boost/log/sources/logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/common.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/attributes.hpp>
#include <boost/log/support/date_time.hpp>

#include <boost/log/utility/setup/file.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/console.hpp>

namespace logging = boost::log;
namespace expr = boost::log::expressions;
namespace attrs = boost::log::attributes;
namespace src = boost::log::sources;
namespace keywords = boost::log::keywords;


// Here we define our application severity levels.
enum class SeverityLevel : size_t {
    TRACE,
        DEBUG,
        INFO,
        WARN,
        ERROR
        };

// The formatting logic for the severity level
template< typename CharT, typename TraitsT >
inline std::basic_ostream<CharT, TraitsT>& operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT, TraitsT> &strm, SeverityLevel lvl) {
    static const char* const str[] = {
        "TRACE",
        "DEBUG",
        "INFO ",
        "WARN ",
        "ERROR"
    };

    if (static_cast<size_t>(lvl) < (sizeof(str) / sizeof(*str))) {
        strm << str[static_cast<size_t>(lvl)];
    } else {
        strm << static_cast<size_t>(lvl);
    }

    return strm;
}

const size_t N = 30;

//NA_LOG_SUBSYSTEM(DEFAULT);

BOOST_LOG_INLINE_GLOBAL_LOGGER_INIT(my_logger, src::severity_logger_mt<SeverityLevel>)
{
    src::severity_logger_mt<SeverityLevel> logger;
    logger.add_attribute("Tag",  attrs::constant<std::string>("DEFAULT"));
    logger.add_attribute("File", attrs::constant<std::string>(__FILE__));

    return logger;
}
void init() {

    // The first thing we have to do is
    // to set up the logging sinks - i.e. where the logs will be written to.
    logging::add_console_log(std::clog,
                            keywords::format = expr::format("%1%|%2%|%3%| %4%")
                            % expr::format_date_time<boost::posix_time::ptime>("TimeStamp", "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f")
                            % expr::attr<SeverityLevel>("Severity")
                            % expr::attr<std::string>("Tag")
                            % expr::message
        );

    attrs::local_clock TimeStamp;
    logging::core::get()->add_global_attribute("TimeStamp", TimeStamp);

    logging::core::get()->set_filter (
        //Write all records with "info" severity or higher
        expr::attr<SeverityLevel>("Severity").or_default(SeverityLevel::INFO) >= SeverityLevel::INFO
        );

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {


    std::cout << "------------ Test Log2 ----------------" << std::endl;

    init();
    src::logger_mt lg;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for (size_t i=0; i<N; ++i) {
        threads.emplace_back([&lg, i]{

                while (true) {
                    BOOST_LOG_SEV(my_logger::get(), SeverityLevel::INFO) << "Thread: " << i;
                }
            });
    }

    for (auto& t : threads) {
        t.join();
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here is a sample of the error I get, the program crash after few minutes.

```
05.04.2017 18:07:37.806122|INFO |DEFAULT| Thread: 5
05.04.2017 18:07:37.806015|INFO |DEFAULT| Thread: 15
05.04.2017 18:07:37.801120|INFO |DEFAULT| Thread: 4
05.04.2017 18:07:37.800895|INFO |DEFAULT| Thread: 25
05.04.2017 18:07:37.799257|INFO |DEFAULT| Thread: 21
05.04.2017 18:07:37.797030|INFO |DEFAULT| Thread: 16
05.04.2017 18:07:37.800260|INFO |DEFAULT| Thread: 8
05.04.2017 18:07:37.797222|INFO |DEFAULT| Thread: 14
05.04.2017 18:07:37.793293|INFO |DEFAULT| Thread: 3
05.04.2017 18:07:37.806708|INFO |DEFAULT| Thread: 18
05.04.2017 18:07:37.793732|INFO |DEFAULT| Thread: 12
05.04.2017 18:07:37.784446|INFO |DEFAULT| Thread: 23
05.04.2017 18:07:37.807030|INFO |DEFAULT| Thread: 20
pure virtual method called
pure virtual method called
pure virtual method called
pure virtual method called
pure virtual method called
pure virtual method called
pure virtual method called
pure virtual method called
pure virtual method called
pure virtual method called
pure virtual method called
pure virtual method called
pure virtual method called
pure virtual method called
pure virtual method called
pure virtual method called
pure virtual method called
pure virtual method called
pure virtual method called
pure virtual method called
pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception
terminate called recursively
terminate called recursively
```

Comment: Do you have a backtrace showing where the pure virtual method is called from?

Comment: Sadly not, 
I ran it again today and got a segfault.
I will try to run gdb on it to see what's going on. I will post the results when I get them.